# Retrieve non-form-element value through form post in Spring 3 MVC Controller Class

Tags: spring-mvc, http-post

When I submit this:

```
<form:form action='/controller.do' method='POST'>
<input type='text' value='test' name='myName" />
<input type='submit'/>
</form:form>
```

How can I retrieve the value of 'myName' in Spring 3 MVC Controller without using form tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you put some plain HTML `<input>` tags inside Spring MVC tag library's `<form:form>` tag.

Though it may work, it probably would be a better idea to use (depending on your situation) either plain HTML:

```
<form action='/controller.do' method='POST'>
   <input type='text' value='' name='myName" />
   <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

or Spring MVC tags only:

```
<form:form action='/controller.do' method='POST' modelAttribute='fooModelAttribute'>
   <form:input path='myName' />
   <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

You can retrieve the `myName` value by declaring the following parameter in your controller method:

```
@RequestParam("myName") String myNameVal
```

Alternatively, you can declare a class which has a `myName` field with a getter and setter (say, `FooClass`). And then you can declare the following parameter in the controller:

```
FooClass foo
```

This parameter may have an optional `@ModelAttribute("fooModelAttribute")` annotation.

See the Spring Reference for more details on [@RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam), [@ModelAttribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args), and [`<form:form>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-formtag).